# Use anchored urls in django (anchored by the id of http objects)

Tags: django, url

My level in front-end development is pretty low.

Nevertheless, I want to implement the very wide-spread behaviour of having several parts anchored in one single page instead of several separate pages, and refer to these parts in the url.

So instead of having `mysite.com/how_to_walk` and `mysite.com/how_to_run` as two different pages and templates, I would like to have one page `mysite.com/how_to_do_stuff` and then depending on if you want to `#walk` or `#run`, refer to the html headers with the id field as suffixes of the url.

I don't really know how to do it with django. I'd like to create only one url dispatcher that - I guess - will look like that:

```
url(r'^how_to_stuff/#(?P<partId>[-\w]*)', views.how_to, name='how_to')
```

...and then I have to create a simple view, but how to refer to the id in the render() call, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. The crucial element is that when the client (browser) goes for such an anchored url `mysite.com/how_to_do_stuff#run`, it sends to the server **only** the root url `mysite.com/how_to_do_stuff` and then applies the anchor to it locally. So you need:

1. A classic, simple url/view/template combination that loads the page `mysite.com/how_to_do_stuff` when it is asked by the client.
2. A way to send the client to these anchored pages and reference them for development. I do this through an other url/view couple that redirects the client to the right anchored url.

Below is the result:

In urls.py:

```
...
url(r'^how_to_do_stuff/(?P<part_id>[-\w]+)', views.how_to_redirect, name='how_to'),
url(r'^how_to_do_stuff', views.how_to)
```

In views.py:

```
def how_to_redirect(request, part_id):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/how_to_do_stuff/#"+part_id)

def how_to(request):
     return render(request, "GWSite/how_to_do_stuff.html")
```

And then I refer to these in my templates through:

```
{% url "how_to" "run"}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [django project website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/)

Take a look at how you they send the num var to views.py

```
# URLconf
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/$', 'blog.views.page'),
    url(r'^blog/page(?P<num>[0-9]+)/$', 'blog.views.page'),
]

# View (in blog/views.py)
def page(request, num="1"):
    # Output the appropriate page of blog entries, according to num.
    ...
```

Comment: That's not really relative to my question that really points at anchors in html pages, through the id of html objects. But thanks anyway!